Brands plugin switchover issue with custom code in WooCommerce
As part of my WooCommerce store, we were using a plugin to facilitate product brands. We originally had a third-party one called YITH Brands. It worked for a while, but it doesn't integrate well with others, so we switched over to the official WC Brands.
The problem is, our previous web developers coded some functionality from YITH into our website, and so disabling this plugin breaks everything.
It appears to be the code that displays the brand name above the product title, as below:
    add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'aq_display_brand_before_title' );
    function aq_display_brand_before_title(){
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();
    $brands = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'yith_product_brand' );
    foreach( $brands as $brand ) echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($brand->term_id).'">'.$brand->name.'</a>';

I've found some similar code in the documentation for WC Brands, but using it doesn't display on the website.
    add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_brands_add_brand_name', 1 );
    function wc_brands_add_brand_name() {
    global $product;
    $brands =  implode(', ', wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(), 'product_brand', ['fields' => 'names']));
    echo "<p>Brand: " . $brands . "</p>";

Is there a way I can alter the first piece of code so that it pulls the variables and such from WC Brands? That way, we keep the functionality and I can safely disable YITH.

Have you verified what exactly that wp_get_post_terms returned?

For official WooCommerce Brands plugin, the taxonomy is "product_brand" instead of "yith_product_brand". With your previous developer code that you provided, there are some missing things to avoid this kind of issue.
Also, it is better to use get_the_terms() as results are cached, avoiding a database query each time the page is displayed.
Replace the code with:
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'aq_display_brand_before_title' );
function aq_display_brand_before_title(){
    global $product;

    $taxonomy    = 'product_brand'; // <= Here we set the correct taxonomy
    $brand_terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), $taxonomy );

    // Check if it's the correct taxonomy and if there are terms assigned to the product 
    if ( $brand_terms && ! is_wp_error( $brand_terms ) ) {
        // Loop through assigned terms
        foreach( $brand_terms as $term ) {
            if ( is_a($term, 'WP_Term') ) {
                echo '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
            }
        }
    }
}

It should work without issue, in a lighter way.

Thanks for this, it appears to be working!

If I may add one thing, there is another piece of code doing the same thing on the product page itself: [yith_wcbr_product_brand show_logo="yes" show_title="yes"]. I can edit this using the UX builder on product layout. With YITH disabled, I just see this code on the public facing page. Do you know how this would be changed to the WC Brands equivalent?

@GrahamToomey Sorry for the delay, to add it in single product pages, try to add the following code line add_action( 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 'aq_display_brand_before_title', 3 ); (uses the same function).

I completely missed your reply to this. Thanks for following up. I added that line in, but it isn't happening. Do I add that beneath the add_action line for the main code above, or if not, where do I place it? Then in UX Builder, I have a text box beneath the Product Title with [product_brand] (formerly [yith_product_brand]. That's still empty. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

@GrahamToomey Maybe your theme is already using some related customizations, so that's why It is not working.
